# Typescript declaration for .js file in mixed project

Tags: typescript

Hi so I'm converting my js react redux project to typescript. and I wanted to start with my redux reducers file.

So this is what my project currently looks like

```
Project/
  ...
  reducers/
     index.ts
  actions/
     index.js
  types/
     actions/
       index.d.ts
  ...
  tsconfig.js
```

File contents -

reducers/index.ts

```
import { Actions } from "../actions";
```

^ with that code i get -

```
[ts] Could not find a declaration file for module '../actions'
```

and in my 
types/
         actions/
           index.d.ts
I have -

```
declare module "actions";
```

in my tsconfig.js i have -

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "esnext",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "jsx": "react",

  "strict": true,

  "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"],
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true
 },
 "exclude": ["node_modules", "typings"]
}
```

So not sure how i can fix -

```
 [ts] Could not find a declaration file for module '../actions'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the module definitions trick (.d.ts).
Try and use --allowJs compiler flag instead while refactoring, typescript does a pretty good job at understanding your .js code.

[Ts config options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "react",
        "strict": true,
        "allowJs": true,  //Allows you to import and compile .js files
        "typeRoots": [
            "./types",
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings"
    ]
}
```

Comment: awesome! that did the job :)